# Qt qml libkakasi.soのライブラリー: エラー: file not recognized: File format not recognized

Tags: linux, ubuntu, qt, qt-creator

libkakasi ライブラリを qt クイック プロジェクトに追加しましたが、ビルド後にエラーが発生します。
この問題を解決するにはどうしたら良いでしょうか？

```
/home/em/LinuxShare/SCOSRZ_Qt_USB/libkakasi.so:-1: error: unrecognized file: unrecognized format file
```

環境:
使用中のqtバージョンはqt create 4.2.1
libkakasi ライブラリ バージョン 2.3.6

Answer (score 1):

`libkakasi.so` (共有ライブラリー: shared object) が unrecognized format file(認識できない書式) というメッセージです

そのアプリのアーキテクチャーと soのアーキテクチャーが異なっていると思われます
(例えば `x86-64`なのに 32bit版を利用しようとした, あるいは別の CPUのライブラリーなど)

以下のように確認できます (`x86-64` であることがわかる)

```bash
$ file /path/to/libkakasi.so
libkakasi.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped
```

可能であれば, ライブラリーも一緒にビルドするとよいかも